# how to add "00" or "+" symbol in front of column values of phone code in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table contains 239 records; each record includes three columns: ***"id, country name, phone code*** ". I need to add a **"00" or "+"** symbol in front of each value of phone code.
ex: (225, 'UNITED KINGDOM', **44**) make it (225, 'UNITED KINGDOM', **+44**)

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? and what is the datatype of phone code column

Comment: can you show us your attempts?

Comment: What do you mean "by one click"? There's nothing to click in SQL. And do the phone number all start with the right country code, just the `'+'` is missing at the beginning? Or can there be number that completely miss the country code or others, that already have `'+'` or `'00'` at the beginning?

Comment: INSERT INTO `country` (`id`,`country`, `phonecode`) VALUES
(1,'AFGHANISTAN', 93),
(2, 'ALBANIA', 355); 
how can I add + or 00 in front  phonecode using sql stetment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `concat`https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat this method helps you to add a string before needed value in mysql

UPD: sorry, I'll explain why concat may help you:

- If you need to add smth to string in MySQL you can use a constructin like this
  `UPDATE tbl SET phone = concat('00', phone))`

The record in your table will look like '00{number you've been entered}'

If you need some kind of conditions, for example your country is the USA, or UK

`UPDATE tbl SET phone= case when country = 'UK' then concat('00', $phone) else concat('+', $phone))`

Or you can use WHERE conditions

`UPDATE tbl SET phone = concat('00', $phone) WHERE country = 'UK'`

Comment: You're getting downvoted because you have a link-only answer. Put a solution in your answer in case that link ever 404's.\

Comment: It's not a link-only answer though. It literally says to use `concat`, which is the correct answer.